# Install Java Card OS on other kind of integrated circuit instead of smart card

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I tried to develop some features of Java Card.

Is it possible to install Java Card OS on other kind of integrated circuit instead of smart card's ? That means maybe I can run applet or some Java Card features on other kind of IC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an java card os available at your hands? To my knowledge there is no free os that implements the JCRE and JCVM. However the specs are open, so potentially this is possible.
However the most feasible approach is to buy the secure chip without Smartcard form factor and couple that to another IC, as only the official chips guarantee you the security for cryptographic use cases.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will continue to develop on smart card.